# Nested Controllers and Directive Scopes Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am having a bit of a problem passing some parameters between controllers and directives in my Angular code. Here is the angular part:

```
<span ng-controller="ListChildren">
            <v-accordion class="vAccordion--default" style="width:80%; margin: auto">
                  <v-pane ng-repeat="child in children">
                    <v-pane-header>

                    </v-pane-header>

                    <v-pane-content>

                    <span>  
                      <a href="/#/activity/{{child._id}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.color, 'color' : child.colorTitle, 'border-color' : child.colorBorder}" ng-class="{'pulsation' : pulse , 'nonpulsation' : !pulse}" ng-init="pulse = false">
                {{child.title}}

                <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.colorSupport, 'color' : child.colorFont}">Current: {{counter | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>
                <span class="badge" ng-style="{'background-color' : child.colorSupport, 'color' : child.colorFont}">Total: {{child.totalTime | secondsToHHmmss }}</span>

            </a>
            <a ng-click="toggle =!toggle; $parent.pulse = !$parent.pulse; toggleTimer()" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-pause' : toggle , 'glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle' : !toggle}"></a>
            <a href="/#/activity/delete/{{child._id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a> 
                    </span>

                    </v-pane-content>

                  </v-pane>
            </v-accordion>
</span>
```

Outside of the "ListChildren" controller, I have another controller (parent?) that populates entries to an HTML page. The "ListChildren" controller then adds children to each one of these entries, when children exist. In essence, there are two nested `ng-repeat` statements going on. To query for children, "ListChildren" uses an end point like this:

```
app.controller('ListChildren',['$scope','$rootScope','$resource','$location', '$routeParams', 
function($scope, $rootScope, $resource, $location, $routeParams){
    var Activities = $resource('/api/activities/children/:id', {id: '@_id'});
    Activities.query(function(activities){
            $scope.children = activities;
            $rootScope.children = activities;
    }); 
}]);
```

Lastly, the `<v-accordion>` directive is there to implement the collapse-expand functionality on the collection of children. I have tested it using basic HTML, so it seems to work.

The problem is that this does not work when I try to use the end-point. Namely, when I test the end-point of some entry with children in the browser, I get a JSON; however, in my application, no children are displayed and I get the following error:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/activities/children 500 (Internal Server
>   Error)

I suspect that somehow I am misunderstanding the scopes on these controllers and directive.

P.S. I tried inserting the `ng-controller="ListChildren"` statement into the `<v-accordion>` tag, but that gives me an error of the directive and controller trying to each use isolated scopes.